# How to add Regex alphabet only to array split on javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to reverse the string. It works, but what I want is it only return alphabet only.

Example:

`wolfrevo` should return `overflow`

`kca456ts` should return `stack`

Here's my code so far

```
function reverseLetter(str) {
 const reverse = str.split(/[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]/).reverse().join("")

 return reverse
}
```

Thank you

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: Why are you using `str.split()` to remove characters? Use `str.replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace()` to remove characters that match the regexp. Then split it after that to get an array that you can reverse.

And you shouldn't have `\d\s:` in the regexp if you only want letters.

```js
function reverseLetter(str) {
  const reverse = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').split("").reverse().join("")

  return reverse
}

console.log(reverseLetter("wolfrevo"));
console.log(reverseLetter("kca456ts"));
```

Comment: Oh, replace(), as the the name suggest, to replace, and also to remove to match the regex. Ok, I got it.  And I'll hone my Regex skills. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: You remove by replacing with an empty string.